# Function returns object instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making a function that checks is there an image in url and it should return true or false depending of success.

```
var image = this.checkImage(imageUrl);
console.log('image: ' + image);

async checkImage(image){
  var a;
  await RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', image)
  .then((res) => {
     a = true;
  })
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
     a = false;
  })

  console.log(a);
  return a;
}
```

`console.log(a);` returns true or false so that works allright, but `console.log('image: ' + image);` returns `[object Object]`

Can you figure out what is wrong in my code?

Comment: parse it to a string `console.log('image:  ' + JSON.stringify(image))`

Comment: It's kinda expected to have that output if you ask me ...

Comment: Async functions always return a promise.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) – async/await don't turn asynchronous functions into synchronous functions.

Answer (score 0):

[Async functions return Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description), and thus your `image` variable is a Promise. Handle it as such:

```
this.checkImage(imageUrl).then(function (image) {
    console.log(image)
})
```

In my browser, `Promise.resolve(value).toString()` returns `'[object Promise]'` rather than `'[object Object]'` as you described, but I believe that the underlying issue remains the same regardless of the Promise implementation.

As a side note, I believe asynchronous functions should be declared as `async function name() {}` rather than `async name() {}`.

Answer (score 0):

an Async Function always returns a Promise. That promise is rejected in the case of uncaught exceptions, and it’s otherwise resolved to the return value of the async function.

```
this.checkImage(imageUrl).then(image => console.log('image: ' + image));;


async checkImage(image){
  var a = await RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', image)
  .then((res) => {
     a = true;
  })
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
     a = false;
  })

  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have to `await` the call to `checkImage`, otherwise it immediately returns a promise.

```
const image = {
  async getImage() {
    // without this await the checkImage fn immediately return a promise
    var image = await this.checkImage('someURL');
    console.log('image: ' + image);
  }

  async checkImage(image){
    var a;
    await fetch(image)
      .then((res) => {
        a = true;
      })
      .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
        a = false;
      })

    console.log(a);
    return a;
  }
}
```

You can put `console.log` in `then` and `catch` to see the order in which they are executed with and without the `await`